# Ansible sudo root hop

Tags: security, ansible, privileges, sudoers

My problem is :

As it is usually seen as a bad practice to use root user to connect to a remote machine over ssh, i use a specific unprivileged account to connect to servers.

But for me it is also a bad practice to do all actions as root user. I prefer use applicative users whenever i can.

With ansible i can become root and execute privileged commands with become directive. But is there any mean to become any user with a root 'hop' privilege escalation ?

ie,
ssh with ssh-user => become root => become any other user

The other means I see do not satisfy me completely:

- become root, use cmd module and use su (which displays the following deprecated message  **[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running su** ) :

  `cmd: su -c "my_command" app_user
  become: True
  become_user: root`
- add sudoers permission to my ssh-user to become directly all applicative users

Am i missing some way to do this more neatly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your playbook with **--ask-become-pass** option, as example:

> ansible-playbook -i ../inventories/production.ini service_install.yml
>   --ask-become-pass

And in your inventory, here is called production.ini, add your information user for ansible group:

```
[group1]
182.26.5.159
182.26.5.160
182.26.5.161
...
[group1:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=appuser                                   # insert your app user here
ansible_ssh_pass=passuser                              # insert your pass here
```

You can then **encrypt** your inventory file to keep your **password** secret, and give the decryption password to your OPs/Sysadmins Teams

> ansible-vault encrypt ../inventories/production.in

The final command kept will be:

> ansible-playbook -i ../inventories/production.ini service_install.yml
>   --ask-become-pass --ask-vault-pass

Then on your play, you will just need to user "**become: yes**" option to call your task:

```
cmd: "my_command" app_user
become: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for details, in fact that is nearly what i use (i connect with ssh keys) but as I say the use of su in command module is deprecated that why i am looking for an other solution.

Comment: OK i guess that is the good solution but that implies to give your ssh user rights to sudo in any users. I guess it does not really matters ...

Answer (score 0):

I've just edited my answer, the task is corrected. Normally it should work without "su" on command.

> cmd: "my_command" app_user become: yes